# Password protect for sendEmail

Tags: python, email, passwords, email-client

I am writing sendEmail Script from external SMTP Client.
I am using my gmail account for sending email.

In this script I need to give my gmail password and username. My question is how
can I keep my password encrypted/secure for such programs.

I think to give direct password in a code is bad practice. But if I will use any kind of encryption how it will work for third party client.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module named [getpass](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) in python standard library.

If you are not fed up with typing your password every time you run the script, I recommend you use it for handling password.

You can also access keyring service of your system via 3rd library, such as [keyring](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring).